# Privnote sockets server did not understand request

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, websocket

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(("privnote.com", 80))
#s = ssl.wrap_socket(s, keyfile=None, certfile=None, server_side=False, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

def claim_note(note_url):
    s.sendall(b'DELETE /'+note_url.encode()+b'HTTP/1.1\r\nX-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\nHost: privnote.com\r\n')
    print(s.recv(4096))
```

This is my code, now let me first start by saying that I have tried so many different things apart from this. I’ve tried https port and http port, 443, 80. I’ve commented and uncommented the statement that wraps the socket with ssl. All with the same outcome. Either the api returning absolutely nothing or the api telling me the request couldn’t be understood by the server. I was looking at a GitHub repo and only one header was used and it was because it was for an Ajax call which was x-requested-with. I tried adding user agent content type and now I’m just using host and x requested with. It’s a DELETE request and the url is the first 8 chars after the link. I’ve also tried adding \r\n\r\n at the end and even tried content-length. I don’t know what else to do. I want to know why the server is saying that.

Comment: As your code currently stands it send an invalid request since there is no final empty line (i.e. `\r\n`). Please fix this and then retry and if it still not works please provide the exact response you've got instead of only your interpretation of it. Please fix code and add information by editing your question (so that error matches code) and not by just providing these information in a comment.

Comment: It’s already in my code... I have tried adding \r\n

Comment: It’s not my interpretation , it literally says “server could not understand your request” with the return headers and 400 status code

Comment: *"It’s already in my code... "* - it's not. You have the request ending with `\r\n` as the line end for the `Host` header line. But there must be an additional `\r\n` after that. If in doubt please refer to the HTTP standard - there is a reason standards exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code. If you actually print out the request you are trying to sent it will look like this:

```
b'DELETE /node_urlHTTP/1.1\r\nX-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\nHost: privnote.com\r\n'
```

There are two problems with this line: a missing space between `/node_url` and `HTTP/1.1` and a missing final `\r\n` als end-of-header marker at the end. Once these are fixed you get a successful response - a 302 redirect to the HTTPS version:

```
b'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nDate:...\r\nLocation: https://privnote.com/node_url ...
```

When repeating the request with HTTPS and a valid node_url (with an invalid node_url you get an error that DELETE is not an allowed method):

```
s.connect(("privnote.com", 443))
s = ssl.wrap_socket(s)

...
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n ...
```

Comment: That’s weird because that’s the method used. It’s easily reproducible , thanks for the information though.

Comment: @Noah: the error only comes if the node url is not known. See updated answer.